# Null pointer Exception in Uploading the xml file

Tags: java, file-upload, saxparser

I have the following code:

```
L2SchemaHandler handler = getSchemaHandler();        

// validate
XMLFormatValidator validator = new XMLFormatValidator(handler.elements, handler.types, handler.root);    

InputStream schemaInput = new FileInputStream(new File(xmlFilePath));

SAXParserFactory spfactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spfactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true);

SAXParser parser = spfactory.newSAXParser();

//this line gives the null pointer Exception
parser.parse(schemaInput, validator);

report.addAll(validator.getReport());
this.objectsList = validator.getObjectList();
// When we know objects are valid, get duplicate objects from db
if(report.isEmpty())
    duplicateObjectsMap    = validateObjectID(validator.getObjects(),report);
    // here we need to check whether object id's exists in db
if(report.isEmpty()){//if no errors have occurred
   //        if(validateObjectID(validator.getObjects(),report))
        validateObjectsFromFile(validator.getObjects(), report , msgreport);
}
```

The marked line gives *Null pointer Exception* while `parser`, `schemaInput` and `validator` contaning the objects not the null value.

Why this line gives the null pointer exception?

Answer (score 0):

To use the validating parser, make the following changes:

```
spfactory.setValidating(true);
```

By default the value of this is set to false.